# Stannous chloride is not dissolving into water

Tags: electrolysis, electroplating

I am trying pcb tin plating. I am following a formula that uses

1. 50ml water
2. 2gm sulfamic acid
3. 0.5gm stannous chloride
4. 3gm thiouria
5. 50ml water

The problem is, my Tin(II) chloride is not dissolving. It is precipitating. I have bought tin (ii) chloride dihydrate. Is there any issue?

Later, I tried to dissolve 0.5gm stannous chloride in only 50ml water. It also precipitated. Also, the tin chloride and water mixture does not attack aluminium or iron (i think it should as per the reactivity series of metal).

Can anyone figure out what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your tin(II) chloride may have oxidized.

Comment: How to double check? The bottle they gave me looks old though. :-/

Comment: Update, I just tried 20ml water, 30ml HCl, 3gm SnCl2. It makes a turbid solution and also the tin plating is not working. Shouldn't it be a clear transparent solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tin chloride $\ce{SnCl2}$ (hydrated or not) is not soluble in pure water. It is quickly hydrolyzed according to : $$\ce{SnCl2 + 2 H2O -> Sn(OH)2 + 2 HCl}$$ and $\ce{Sn(OH)2}$ is insoluble in water.  To dissolve $\ce{SnCl2}$, this reaction has to be reversed by adding $\ce{HCl}$ in $5$ M solution. In this case, a clear solution is obtained.

Unfortunately $\ce{SnCl2}$ solutions are easily oxidized by oxygen from the air, and transformed into $\ce{SnCl4}$ plus a basic and not very soluble salt $\ce{Sn(OH)Cl}$, according to : $$\ce{6 SnCl2 + O2 + 2 H2O -> SnCl4 + 4 Sn(OH)Cl}$$ If a pure solution of $\ce{SnCl2}$ is wanted, this reaction can be avoided by adding some metallic tin grains ($\ce{Sn}$), which react and reduce $\ce{SnCl4}$ according to : $$\ce{SnCl4 + Sn -> 2 SnCl2}$$ It should also be mentioned that the solutions of $\ce{SnCl4}$ are also slowly hydrolyzed at high dilution.

Ref.: F. P. Treadwell, Analyse qualitative, Dunod Ed. Paris, 1924.

F. A. Cotton, G. Wilkinson, Advanced Inorganic Chemistry, Interscience Pub., J. Wiley, New York, 1972, p. 330 - 331